# Sorting collection of objects in java

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I would like to sort the students by age using my created sort function, but I am not sure if I need to implement the comparator / comparable on this part.

I have the following POJO:

```
public class Student {

 private String name;
 private int age;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
}
```

Created an interface:

```
public interface CollectionsProblem {
    public void sort(Collection<Student> memes, boolean ascending);
}
```

And here is the implementation of the interface:

```
public class CollectionsProblemImpl implements CollectionsProblem { 
    public void sort(Collection<Student> students, boolean ascending) { 
        /****Need to add some sorting here in order to sort students by age 
          param0 - students: the collection to sort
          param1 - ascending: true if the collection should be sorting in ascending order, otherwise false***
    */ 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: If it's your own sorting algorithm, you can do however you want. Sorting a Collection in-place doesn't make sense though: you'll never be able to sort a HashSet, for example, as HashSet elements don't have any index in the set.. The method should take a List as argument. Or it should take a Collection, but create a sorted copy and thus return a List.

Answer (score 0):

You can either implement `Comparable` in your `Student` POJO class or write a separate comparator by implementing `Comparator` interface , lets say

```
public class StudentComparatorByAge implements  Comparator<Student>  {
@Override
public int compare(Object Obj1 , Object Obj2){
}
}
```

. Then you use `Collections.sort(studentArray);` ( if implementing `Comparable` ) or `Collections.sort(studentArray,StudentComparatorByAgeObj );` ( if writing separate comparator ) . You also need to create `StudentComparatorByAgeObj`  instance from `StudentComparatorByAge`.

Your `CollectionsProblem` interface doesn't make sense as you don't need to write your own sort function - that is already provided by `Collections` class. Comparison logic is yours to worry.

Answer (score 0):

If sorting in place is not required I would use java's 8 stream:

```
students.stream()
            .sorted(comparator)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You could even change your interface to allow user to provide custom collector:

```
public interface CollectionsProblem {
    <R, A> R sort(Collection<Student> students, boolean ascending, Collector<? super Student, A, R> collector);
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class CollectionsProblemImpl implements CollectionsProblem {
public <R, A> R sort(Collection<Student> students, boolean ascending, Collector<? super Student, A, R> collector) {
    final int order = ascending ? 1 : -1;
    Comparator<Student> comparator = new Comparator<Student>() {
        public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
            return order * Integer.compare(o1.getAge(), o2.getAge());
        }
    };

    return students.stream()
            .sorted(comparator)
            .collect(collector);
}
```

And usage:

```
Student a = new Student();
a.setAge(19);
Student b = new Student();
b.setAge(18);

List<Student> students = Lists.newArrayList(a, b);
CollectionsProblem problem = new CollectionsProblemImpl();
List<Student> sortedList = problem.sort(students, true, Collectors.<Student>toList());
```

Of course passing i.e. `Collectors.toSet()` wouldn't have much sense in this case.

Comment: What does it mean by R and A at the function definition : public <R, A> R sort(Collection<Meme> memes, boolean ascending, Collector<? super Meme, A, R> collector)

Comment: These are from Collector's api - it has 3 generics. Take a look at javadoc of Collector: `param <T> The type of input elements for the new collector` `param <A> The intermediate accumulation type of the new collector` `param <R> The final result type of the new collector` In case of `toList` collector these are in order: `T, ?, List<T>` and in your case `T -> Student`